# Is there a way to access formik's submit function, values and other props from a parent component

Tags: reactjs, formik

Use Case:

My components structure contains a main component which has few child components along with the RMWC Drawer Component.

On click of drawer list, particular component will be rendered.

1. Each child component is form, we are using formik.
2. Previously each child component has a save button, on click of that will perform save operation.
3. Now I want to call save from parent on click of drawer menu.

So, Is there a way to access formik's submit function, values and other props from a parent component.

Comment: You could pass a function in from the parent, that, when called, sets the state of the parent with the formik object. Or, you could just bring the the formik wrapper up a layer.

Comment: You can try to use share data and put anything in it via middleware of validator like in this example - https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/271#issuecomment-407869424

Answer (score 0):

I think is not a good think to do, but you can use forwardRef with useImperativeHandle:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

With this tecnique the child can expose some methods that parent can calls with the next:

```
childRef.current.method()
```

In alternative you can pass throught a global state (for example with redux) and link each component to it

Comment: In react docs, it is given that we can not use ref on functional components. Is there a way to use ref in functional components?